# How to show an entity detail inside children without causing inifinite recursion

Tags: java, recursion, jackson, spring-data

Im trying to get json from a spring repo, but on the client side, we need the parent detail inside the children itself.

**Example: (What i got)**

```
car:{
    make:'volvo',
    color:'blue',
    hp:225,
    extras:{
       //(...)
    }
}
```

**Example: (What i want)**

```
car:{
    make:'volvo',
    color:'blue',
    hp:225,
    extras:{
        //(...)
        car:{
             // car to which extras belong, but without the "extras" property again
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this without causing an infinite recursion? (preferably through annotations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following workaround.

In the `Extras` class:

```
@JsonProperty("cardetail")
public Car getCarDetail(){
    Car _car = new Car();
    // (...)Clone of the original Object, ignoring the "extras"
    return _car;
}
```

Which results in almost what i wanted but with a different name

Answer (score 1):

**`OPTION 1:`** You can use

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
```

on you **`Car`** and **`Extras`** entities.

**`Option 2:`**
Use **`@JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference`**

```
 @JsonManagedReference  part of reference that gets serialized normally.

 @JsonBackReference part of reference that will be omitted from serialization.
```

**`Option 3:`**

You can use the **`@JsonIgnore`** annotation to simply ignore one of the sides of the relationship, thus breaking the chain.

For more information [visit here.](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)